# apt-get install apache2 wont' install configuration files

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I had some problems with apache2, so I decide to get a fresh start.
sudo apt-get --purge apache2
It won't clear my config files. So I manually rm the /etc/apache2 folder.
Then "sudo apt-get install apache2" won't create /etc/apache2 folder anymore. Tried clear apt/cache, won't help. Tried update/change different source.list, won't help.

Any hint there the problem might be?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Remove with sudo apt-get --purge remove

Comment: installed again with "sudo apt-get install apache2". The apt-get does not create any config file for me. 
Then used "sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2".
Then used "sudo apt-get install apache2"
The apt-get does not create any config file. So it does not help.

Comment: Try installing with aptitude

Comment: This helped me - https://askubuntu.com/questions/703263/problem-installing-apache2, in contrast to answer in this question.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration files are created on the installation of the package `apache2.2-common`. The command `apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-common` should do the trick.